# Email the Log file created at the end of Program using Serilog

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, scheduler, serilog

I am using Serilog library in a C# Console Application to build a Scheduler, which logs messages in a Log File for each day.  The filenames are created dynamically using below code.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.WriteTo.Console()
.WriteTo.File("logs\\log-scheduler-.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
.CreateLogger();
```

How can I get to know the Name of File that my Console application has created?  At the end of my program, I want to email the log file as attachment.

Comment: By getting files from `logs` folder and then get a latest one

Comment: That's the final option, if Serilog does not have any inbuilt way. I will also ask this feature in Serilog GitHub, to see if they can bring this feature.

Comment: try this : https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-email

Comment: At what stage email will be trigger? I don't want to send mail for every line of message I log?

Comment: How did you end up solving this @kamleshrao? I also want to send the log file upon error, not one mail per line

Answer (score 4):

Serilog doesn't expose a way to inspect the name of the file(s) that were created, as of this writing.

If you don't use a `RollingInterval` and have the log messages be written to a single file, then you know exactly what the name of the file is, because you already specified it in the log pipeline configuration: `logs\\log-scheduler-.txt`.

But if you want to use a `RollingInterval` then you what you could do, is to inspect the folder where your log files are being written to, and find the log file(s) that were updated since your application started, by capturing the current timestamp when your app starts, and then  looking at the `LastWriteTimeUtc` attribute of the log files in the file system to see anything that has changed since that time.

e.g.

```
DateTime appStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

// ... (app code)

// Ensure that all messages are flushed to the file
Log.CloseAndFlush();

// Get all log files modified since the app started
var logFilesUpdatedInThisSession = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp\logs\")
    .EnumerateFileSystemInfos("log-scheduler-*.txt")
    .Where(f => f.LastWriteTimeUtc >= appStartTime)
    .OrderBy(f => f.LastWriteTimeUtc)
    .ToList();

if (logFilesUpdatedInThisSession.Any())
{
    // Send all files via e-mail ...
}
```

---

Another alternative (better IMO) would be to *not* send e-mails at all from your app, and just ship the logs to a server, such as a [Seq](https://datalust.co/seq) server which allows you to easily browse the logs, apply filters, etc., which is a much better experience than opening a log file attached to an e-mail on a text editor.

[image: Seq]